# Rails Scaffold did not update after new database migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a newbie to Rails, so I've been creating scaffolding because it seemed easiest.

After a while I realized I had to change the name of some of the database table columns, so I performed a migration and used rename_column function. But, this has not changed in the scaffold, so now that I run a test I get a lot of errors because a field that used to be ex. **user_name** and is now **username** has not been updated in tests, javascript files etc.

Is there a way to update all the files the Scaffold created to match the new fields in the database automatically? It seems quite daunting to change all of it by hand.

Hope the question makes sense. I'm not particularly familiar with rails vernacular just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there's no way the migration can change wahtever is done in other rails generators, 'cause that can mess up many things and upscale concurency. You should just use find_and_replace engine through your project files. 
I prefer to use `JetBrains RubyMine IDE` to be able to refactor that kind of things.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll have to find and replace then. Thanks for your reply